# How to manage Layout In android

Tags: android

I had just started working on android. Actually I had created a calculator application.
The problem I have faced is to manage the layout. I have two rows of buttons. In each row are 4 buttons. When I run the application the space between the first row and the second row is quite large. So can anyone tell me how can I decrease the space between these two rows?

The code I have written:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculator Application"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/entry"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:layout_below="@id/label"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/one"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                        android:text="1" />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/two"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                        android:text="2" />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/three"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                        android:text="3" />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/plus"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                        android:text="+" />

                </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/four"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="4" />
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/five"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="5" />
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/six"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="6" />
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/minus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="-" />
                </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/seven"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="7" />
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/eight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="8" />
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/nine"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="9" />
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/multiply"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="*" />
                </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1">
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/zero"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="0" />
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/clr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="c" />
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/equal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="=" />
                <Button
                android:id="@+id/divide"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:text="/" />
                </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Regards
Anshuman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace all of the
`android:layout_height="fill_parent"` calls to
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
 (apart from the parent layout, which should be `fill_parent`)
I have verified that this works.

EDIT: To make the buttons fill the screen horizontally, (and all be equally sized), add this to each button:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: yeh CaspNZ its working..but the size of buttons are not same..some become large..some small ...how can i manage the size of the each buttons of same size..moreover i want the the edit text box and and all the buttons to be wrap in one container..

Comment: See above for fix. I'm not sure what you mean by "all the buttons be wrapped in one container" - it looks like they are already...

Comment: Hi Anshuman, if you like this solution, generally you "accept" it as the correct answer and / or you upvote it - that gives me an incentive to answer any other questions that you might have.

Answer (score 0):

the better way  is u can use grid layout.try this links

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/draw-menu-in-grid-view/

http://www.firstdroid.com/2011/02/06/android-tutorial-gridview-with-icon-and-text/

Comment: Yes you are exactly right about to use Gridview as Anshuman is having calculator kind of application having fixed number of buttons in a row so its preferrable to use Gridview. And yes, Don't prefer to use LinearLayout for such case, if you still want to use then use Relative Layout because it takes less time to load.

Answer (score 0):

As CaspNZ suggested use `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` also using `top padding` may help.